# UIMA Pipeline with Stanford NER

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, uima

I have integrated Stanford NER in UIMA and developed a pipeline.
The pipeline contains a FileSystemCollectionReader,an NERAnnotator and a CasConsumer but the output so come isn't desired. In my input directory i have two files and after running the pipeline, i get two files as ouput but the second file is getting merged with the first file in second ouput. I don't know what's happening here.

The code for CasConsumer:

`

```
 package org.gds.uima;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.uima.UimaContext;
import org.apache.uima.analysis_component.AnalysisComponent_ImplBase;
import org.apache.uima.analysis_component.CasAnnotator_ImplBase;
import org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase;
import org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException;
import org.apache.uima.cas.CAS;
import org.apache.uima.cas.CASException;
import org.apache.uima.cas.Type;
import org.apache.uima.cas.text.AnnotationFS;
import org.apache.uima.fit.component.CasConsumer_ImplBase;
import org.apache.uima.fit.component.JCasConsumer_ImplBase;
import org.apache.uima.fit.descriptor.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.apache.uima.fit.util.CasUtil;
import org.apache.uima.jcas.JCas;
import org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException;


public class CasConsumer extends JCasConsumer_ImplBase
{
    public final static String PARAM_OUTPUT="outputDir";

     @ConfigurationParameter(name = PARAM_OUTPUT)
     private String outputDirectory;

     public final static String PARAM_ANNOTATION_TYPES = "annotationTypes";


    enter code here
     @ConfigurationParameter(name = PARAM_ANNOTATION_TYPES,defaultValue="String")
     public List<String> annotationTypes;

     public void initialize(final UimaContext context) throws ResourceInitializationException 
     {
         super.initialize(context);
     }

     @Override
     public void process(JCas jcas)
     {

            String original = jcas.getDocumentText();

            try
            {
                String onlyText="";
                JCas sofaText = jcas.getView(NERAnnotator.SOFA_NAME);
                onlyText = sofaText.getDocumentText();
                String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(20);   
                    File outputDir = new File(this.outputDirectory+"/"+name);
                    System.out.print("Saving file to "+outputDir.getAbsolutePath());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputDir.getAbsoluteFile());
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
                    pw.println(onlyText);
                    pw.close();

            }
            catch(CASException cae)
            {
                System.out.println(cae);
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fne)
            {
                System.out.print(fne);
            }               
    }



}
`
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Could you paste the console output as well please.

Comment: I have resolved the issue now. Thanks anyways!

Comment: could you put your solution as answer here, and close the question? Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong in this class. I made some changes to the other class and it worked like a charm!